# date format conversion in MySQL

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have datetime saved in varchar field in format `15.03.2014 11:50:18:60`

How do I change the format in `2014-03-15 11:50:18.60`

Comment: Which DBMS? Your headline say`s mysql but the tag says sql-server?

Comment: Where is the time value in input (11:50:18.60)?

Comment: @Jesuraja, the above data given are only examples for the format.

Comment: You should give proper input and expected output. `Here input is March 15, expected output is July 15`. How it is possible? Just think about it....

Answer (score 1):

Ok, firstly I will state the obvious: don't use a varchar datatype for datetimes.

Most likely not your fault and you've inherited this, but the problem still remains, therefore you require to convert from varchar to datetime and format it.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), mycolumn, 120) FROM mytable
```

You can change the output format to any time style you require. E.g. 120 for yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss(24h) format.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select CONVERT(datetime, '15.03.2014 00:00:00', 104)
```

The `CONVERT` function is used here to convert from `varchar` to `datetime`. The third argument is the key, since it specifies the format for the `datetime` value.

More on this [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL (except I don't know what the `:60` is):

```
mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('15.03.2014 11:50:18:60', '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i:%s');
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE('15.03.2014 11:50:18:60', '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i:%s') |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2014-03-15 11:50:18                                        |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
```